# Computing the image of $f$ under the Laplace-Beltrami operator with metric tensor $g_{x,y}=(c + \alpha(x))dx^2 + \beta(x)dy^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

**Remark:** This will be one an attempt at a "fail fast" post and it is likely that a standard textbook contains answer to this question. The problem is that I am so new to the Laplace-Beltrami operator and metric tensors that I have not found a reference which I could apply in this situation.

Let $c > 0$ be a fixed and $\alpha,\beta$ be positive continuously differentiable functions on $x$ alone. Suppose that our ambient manifold is some compact subset $K\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ and our metric tensor is given by $g_{x,y}=(c + \alpha(x))dx^2 + \beta(x)dy^2$ at $(x,y)\in K$

I am looking to compute the image of a nice-enough function $f$ under the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_g=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\partial_i\left(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ij}\partial_j f\right)$, where $|g|$ stands for the determinant of the matrix representation of $g$ and $g^{ij}$ the $ij$th entry of the inverse of the matrix representation of $g$.

I think that in our case the matrix representation of $M_{g_\cdot}$ is given by

$$M_{g_{x,y}}=\begin{bmatrix}(c + \alpha(x)) & 0\\\ 0 & \beta(x)\end{bmatrix}$$

with an inverse

$$M_{g_{x,y}}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}(c + \alpha(x))^{-1} & 0\\\ 0 & \beta(x)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$

therefore by denoting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=f_x$, I believe that for nice enough $f$

\begin{align}
\Delta_gf(x,y) &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(c+\alpha(x))\beta(x)}}\bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\sqrt{(c+\alpha(x))\beta(x)}(c + \alpha(x))^{-1}f_x(x,y)\right) \\
&+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\sqrt{(c+\alpha(x))\beta(x)}\beta(x)^{-1}f_y(x,y)\right)\bigg) \\
&= \frac{f_{xx}(x,y)}{c + \alpha(x)} + f_x(x,y)\cdot \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\sqrt{\beta(x)}}{\sqrt{c + \alpha(x)}}\right)(x,y) + \frac{f_{yy}(x,y)}{\beta(x)}
\end{align}

where I have decided to omit the actual computation of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\sqrt{\beta(x)}}{\sqrt{c + \alpha(x)}}$. Besides this omission, do these computations seem correct?

Comment: I didn't carefully check whether there is a small typo somewhere but otherwise yes, this looks fine, that is the way to compute this. Of course you need to check that your square roots are all of positive numbers and that the involved functions are all sufficiently nice and differentiable.